# Converting data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am loading in a bunch of data that contains dates formatted as shown below:

00-JAN-0000
00-FEB-0000
00-MAR-0000
00-APR-0000
00-MAY-0000
00-JUN-0000
00-JUL-0000
00-AUG-0000
00-SEP-0000
00-OCT-0000
00-NOV-0000
oo-DEC-0000

SQL cannot automatically convert these dates because it does not recognize the month part of the date. I have approx 50,000 records to import. Any ideas?

**OP has said in a comment:**

> **The data I am working with are
>   client's date of birth. Since I did
>   not want to post someone's DOB online,
>   I masked the day and the year with 0s
>   but I left the month intact as that is
>   what is causing the problem.**

Comment: Those are not valid dates, as there is no date `0`. How are you expecting the date to look once imported?

Comment: You maybe should give some more information. What sql-server, what kind of os. what utils you have available - sed, awk, ... ?

Comment: I'm thinking he is just showing the dates with 0 as placeholders to demonstrate the format, not the actual data.

Comment: @OrbMan - I realize that the data I posted are invalid dates since there is no date 0. I put that out just for example purposes. The important part is that the month is formatted as shown above. I would prefer to keep the date in a dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: @txwikinger - This will be deployed on a SQL 2000 server. As far as other server configurations, I have no idea since I have no direct access to the server.

Comment: For a little more background; I am receiving a non-delimited text file that I am bulk inserting into a single-column temp table. I am then doing an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement to load the data into my final table utilizing SUBSTRING to split my data into the correct columns. However, this is failing because of the format of the dates in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you importing?

Are you sure one of the dates isn't a bit iffy? your (real-non-zero) date dd-mmm-yyyy format should be accepted by SQL server;

```
select convert(datetime, '12-NOV-1975')
1975-11-12 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL can recognize the month part of the date, but it can't recognize your day (zero) or year (also zero). If you have to use BULK INSERT, try this:

- Load the data into an interim table, with the column set as char(11)
- Copy (INSERT...SELECT...) the data over to your target table

Conversion code would be something like:

```
INSERT MyTable (MyDate)
 select '01' + substring(@foo, 4, 3) + cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))
 from MyInterimTable
```

(This would set it to the first day of the current year.)

Comment: The data I am working with are client's date of birth. Since I did not want to post someone's DOB online, I masked the day and the year with 0s but I left the month intact as that is what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a staging table where you have a `YourDateString` column to be populated by the data, and then an actual datetime column `YourDate`, which you will update in a different step.  like this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table(YourDateString varchar(11), YourDate datetime)

--simulate bulk load
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('01-JAN-1976',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('02-FEB-1980',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('05-MAR-1991',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('12-APR-1997',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('22-MAY-1990',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('18-JUN-1971',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('17-JUL-1988',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('19-AUG-1993',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('19-SEP-1970',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('04-OCT-1982',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('08-NOV-1970',null)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('18-DEC-1983',null)

--convert to proper datetime
UPDATE @YourTable
    SET YourDate= CONVERT(datetime,YourDateString)

--show data
select * from @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourDateString YourDate
-------------- -----------------------
01-JAN-1976    1976-01-01 00:00:00.000
02-FEB-1980    1980-02-02 00:00:00.000
05-MAR-1991    1991-03-05 00:00:00.000
12-APR-1997    1997-04-12 00:00:00.000
22-MAY-1990    1990-05-22 00:00:00.000
18-JUN-1971    1971-06-18 00:00:00.000
17-JUL-1988    1988-07-17 00:00:00.000
19-AUG-1993    1993-08-19 00:00:00.000
19-SEP-1970    1970-09-19 00:00:00.000
04-OCT-1982    1982-10-04 00:00:00.000
08-NOV-1970    1970-11-08 00:00:00.000
18-DEC-1983    1983-12-18 00:00:00.000

(12 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered the problem. As I looked through the data I was sent, I see where, on some records, the previous field was null. When I split out the date then, I am only getting the last two digits of the year. That is what is throwing my error. Thanks to everyone for their help.